# For loop enters only individual strings into a list, not entire words

Tags: python, string, loops

I am newish to programming and one issue I am having is this. Sometimes when I try to enter strings into a list using a for loop, the individual characters in the string are entered as separate entries, rather than as entire words. 
Here is my code.

```
my_favourite_fruits = []


ask_user = int(input("How many favourite fruits do you have? : "))

for i in range(ask_user):
    kk = input("Enter a favourite fruit: ")
    my_favourite_fruits += kk


print("Here is a list of your favourite fruits: ", my_favourite_fruits)
```

And here is the output.

Enter a favourite fruit: banana
Enter a favourite fruit: orange
Enter a favourite fruit: apple
Here is a list of your favourite fruits:  `['b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'e', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']`

I have experimented with this a lot, and I'm not sure at all why this happens. I appreciate any help, thank you for reading.

Comment: Hello Fergal, welcome to SO. Could you please indicate in the tags which programming language you are using. It will help experts to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using python language. In Python there is one in-built function list;

```
my_favourite_fruits = []
ask_user = int(input("How many favourite fruits do you have? : "))
for i in range(ask_user):
    kk = input("Enter a favourite fruit: ")
    my_favourite_fruits += list(kk)
print("Here is a list of your favourite fruits: ", my_favourite_fruits)`
```

Output:

```
How many favourite fruits do you have? : 2
Enter a favourite fruit: banana
Enter a favourite fruit: apple
Here is a list of your favourite fruits:  ['b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `append` to add items to a list

**Example**

```py
my_favourite_fruits = []


ask_user = int(input("How many favourite fruits do you have? : "))

for i in range(ask_user):
    kk = input("Enter a favourite fruit: ")
    my_favourite_fruits.append(kk)


print("Here is a list of your favourite fruits: ", my_favourite_fruits)
```

### Usage

**input**

`How many favourite fruits do you have? : 2`

`Enter a favourite fruit: Hello`

`Enter a favourite fruit: World`

**output**

`Here is a list of your favourite fruits: ['Hello', 'World']`